# Class properties in VB.NET 4.0

Tags: .net, vb.net

I've been assigned to document some new code, and I can't figure out how the code below works. This is the new `Sub` for a public class.

I am guessing that "r" stands for row, but how are the three properties getting the data? I can't find anything in the code that would help shed light on this.

```
Protected Sub New(ByVal r As DataRow)
    UserID = r.Field(Of Int32)("userID")
    OfficialGroupID = r.Field(Of Guid?)("officialGroupID")
    WorkID = r.Field(Of Int32)("workID")
End Sub
```

What is happening here?

<sub>(I'm new to .NET, coming from [ASP Classic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages).)</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a constructor - it's getting a DataRow passed to it ("r"), and using the values of the fields within that row to initialize its properties.

Basically, when this type is created, you have to pass it a `DataRow` that's already initialized (and has all of the values).  The three properties (`UserID`, `WorkID`, and `OfficialGroupID`) of the object will get their values from the "userID", "workID", etc. fields of the row.

Comment: oh ok, so some other class would call it like New MyClass(dataset)?

Comment: @999cm999 Yes.  Likely in a loop through each row of a table, or via a LINQ query...

Comment: Wow there are over 8000 userIDs...so this would generate over 8000 instances of this class?  Doesn't that seem bad?

Comment: @999cm999 It depends - it might be what the original developer wanted, but it might be a bad idea.  It's tough to know.  That being said, teh loop may be over a query result, in which case it could just create this for a small subset...

Answer (score 1):

`r` is a [DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx). It has an extension method of `.Field`:

```
WorkID = r.Field(Of Int32)("workID")
```

It means: set `WorkID` to the value of the column in the data row with the name "workID" and the type of that value is `Int32`.